# Program for simplifying expressions of many-body Pauli operators

Tags: computational-physics

I have a system of $N$ spins, with the usual $\sigma_i^{x,y,z}$ operators defined on each site (operators at different sites commute). I would like to find a program, perhaps in Mathematica, with the ability to simplify down complicated expressions involving products and commutators of these matrices, i.e.
$$[\sigma^x_1 \sigma^y_2, [\sigma^y_2, \sigma^x_2]] = 4 \sigma^x_1 \sigma^z_2$$
The individual manipulations are straightforward, but you can imagine things getting much more complicated by adding more and more terms, so I would like to find some systematic way of doing this.

Comment: It shouldn’t be too hard to write this in Mathematica.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about obtaining software and not physics.

Comment: @KyleKanos I would propose migrating it to [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). It would be better there, as opposed to being simply closed here.

Answer (score -1):

There is a [SymPy module Pauli Algebra](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/paulialgebra.html) in Python that is tailored exactly for this purpose.

[SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) is a very popular and well supported Python library for symbolic mathematics, so I think you should be able to get your simplified expressions.